# How to create pivot table with two different aggregations

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset on which I would like to run multiple aggregation steps using. This code creates the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                    'S': [200, 100, 300, 400],
                    'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01']).date,
                    'Value': [5, 10, 30, 40]})
```

yielding:

```
df1: 
  Name    S        Date  Value
0    A  200  2019-01-01      5
1    A  100  2019-01-01     10
2    B  300  2019-02-01     30
3    B  400  2019-03-01     40
```

The final result of the aggregations should look like this:

```
                2019-01-01  2019-02-01  2019-03-01
A   100, 200            15      
B   300 - 400                       30          40
```

The first step I did was

```
df2 = df.groupby(by=['Name', 'Date']).agg({'S': lambda x: ', '
                             .join(pd.DataFrame([str(s) for s in x]).drop_duplicates()
                                                                    .sort_values(by=0)
                                                                    .iloc[:, 0]
                                                                    .map(str)),
                            'Value': np.sum,})
```

The `.join(...)` part is a bit convoluted but takes the numbers in `S`, drops duplicates, sorts, and concatenates them to a string.

The result is this:

```
df2: 
                        S  Value
Name Date                       
A    2019-01-01  100, 200     15
B    2019-02-01       300     30
     2019-03-01       400     40
```

and now I am stuck. I can generate the following:

```
df3 = (df2.pivot_table('Value', index=['Name', 'S'], columns=['Date'], 
                      aggfunc={'Value': np.sum})
                    .fillna(0)
                    .reset_index()
                    )
```

```
df3: 
Date Name         S  2019-01-01  2019-02-01  2019-03-01
0       A  100, 200        15.0         0.0         0.0
1       B       300         0.0        30.0         0.0
2       B       400         0.0         0.0        40.0
```

However, I would like the two last lines to be combined, with `S` becoming `300 - 400` (similar to the join for `df2`). I have not found out how I can combine those aggregations into one step (mixing `groupby` and `pivot_table`).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you should consider creating a pandas interval_range for the dataframe. that will make the overall data more consistent to manipulate across records. And very likely much faster to process on large dataframes than the solution offered here. you can change the input data structure to make the dataframe internally more symmetric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
val=df1.groupby(['Name','Date'])['Value'].sum().reset_index() # get aggregate sum of values
ind=df1.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: '-'.join([str(i) for i in x.S.values])).reset_index() # Prepare index for target dataframe
target_df=ind.merge(val, on=['Name']).pivot_table(index=['Name', 0], columns=['Date'], values='Value').fillna(0) # Merge both and pivot to get desired output
```

Then, `print(target_df)` gives desired output:

```
Date          2019-01-01  2019-02-01  2019-03-01
Name 0                                          
A    200-100        15.0         0.0         0.0
B    300-400         0.0        30.0        40.0
```

Answer (score 0):

@Parth gave the correct insight, that it is not possible to do both steps (aggregate numbers and `pivot_table` the data, and at the same time run a `groupby`), but you have to separate creation of the future index, and then pivoting the data.

Here is my final code (slight variation from @parth's):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                    'S': [200, 100, 300, 400],
                    'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-01']).date,
                    'Value': [5, 10, 30, 40]})

print('df1: \n', df1, '\n')

df2 = df.groupby(by=['Name', 'Date']).agg({'S': lambda x: ', '
                             .join(pd.DataFrame([str(s) for s in x]).drop_duplicates()
                                                                    .sort_values(by=0)
                                                                    .iloc[:, 0]
                                                                    .map(str)),
                            'Value': np.sum,})
print('df2:\n ', df2, '\n')

ind = (df2.groupby(by=['Name']).agg({'S': lambda x: ' - '.join(pd.DataFrame([str(s) for s in x])
                                                          .drop_duplicates()
                                                          .sort_values(by=0)
                                                          .iloc[:, 0]
                                                          .map(str))})
                             .reset_index())
print('ind:\n', ind, '\n')

val = df1.groupby(['Name','Date'])['Value'].sum().reset_index() # get aggregate sum of values
print('val:\n', val, '\n')

df3 = (ind.merge(val, on=['Name'])
          .pivot_table(index=['Name', 'S'], columns=['Date'], values='Value')
          .fillna(0)
          )
print('df3\n', df3)
```